# Laravel pulling information from wrong rows? Explain?

Tags: laravel

I'm using laravel 5.5 and I have this code

```
$building = Building::findOrFail($building_id);

$units = $building->units()
                ->whereHas('parkingspaces',function($query) use($request){
                    $query->where('name','=', $request->search );
                })
                ->orWhereHas('users',function($query) use($request){
                    $query->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
                })
                ->get();
```

The results I'm getting are wrong, I want it to search through the building's unit's user/tenant names. But it's going into other buildings and doing the search too. So I'm getting units showing up from other buildings in the results..

I thought that by having the **$building** set, it would make all queries deeper down search within it.

`$building->units()->with(['users','parkingspaces'])->get();`, gets the correct units with users and parking spaces attached to the unit.

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong?

---

Note: `Auth::user()->current_building()` grabs ID of building from session.

Building Model Snippet

```
class Building extends Model{
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','buildings_users');
  }



 public function tenants(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','buildings_users')->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', '=', 'resident');
        });
  }

  public function staff(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','buildings_users')->whereHas('roles',function($query){
            $query->where('name','!=','tenant')->where('name','!=','administrator')->where('name','!=','superadministrator');
        });
  }

  public function managers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','buildings_users')->whereHas('roles',function($query){
            $query->where('name','=','manager');
        });
  }

  public function units(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Unit');
  }
```

Unit Model Snippet

```
class Unit extends Model
{
    //
    public function building(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Building');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_unit');
    }

    public function parkingspaces(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Parkingspace');
    }
```

building_users

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buildings_users` (
  `building_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

user_unit

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_unit` (
  `building_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

units snippet

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `units` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `building_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

parkingspaces

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parkingspaces` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `building_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=108 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Post your Building model and database structure.

Comment: @Konafets just added a few snippets, going through the migrations to get the rest of the info. Or is it enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the ungrouped `orWhereHas()` call.

Your `$building->units()` relationship builds a sql query something like:

```
select * from units
where
    units.building_id = ?
    and units.building_id is not null
```

You're then adding where conditions for your relationships onto this base query, so your query ends up being something like:

```
select * from units
where
    units.building_id = ?
    and units.building_id is not null
    and exists([parkingspaces query])
    or exists([users query])
```

That last `or` condition is why you're getting the extra records. Even if all three of the first conditions are false, if the last condition matches, the record will be returned (`false AND false AND false OR true === true`).

What you need to do is to group your where conditions, so that your `or` condition will be properly scoped (`false AND false AND (false OR true) === false`). You do this by passing a closure to the `where()` call:

```
$units = $building->units()
    ->where(function ($query) use($request){
        return $query
            ->whereHas('parkingspaces',function($query) use($request){
                $query->where('name','=', $request->search );
            })
            ->orWhereHas('users',function($query) use($request){
                $query->where('name','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
            });
    })
    ->get();
```

This will generate a query something like:

```
select * from units
where
    units.building_id = ?
    and units.building_id is not null
    and (
        exists([parkingspaces query])
        or exists([users query])
    )
```

Now your `or` condition is properly scoped, and you'll only get results for the building with the matching id.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Didn't know I could use where(function($query){}) like that, though I've used it in WhereHas method.

Comment: @Darius No problem. And thanks for fixing that missing `use ($request)` in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The "has-many-through" relationship provides a convenient shortcut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation.

```
// In your User model
public function units()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Unit::class, Building::class);
}
```

That way you can simply access the units directly through the user:

```
$units = Auth::user()->units;
```

Instead of doing a query to access the user's building and then doing another query to access that building's units, Laravel would use a single query with a join to get you the members.

`hasManyThrough` relationship Laravel docs:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: That certainly helps, but this list is for listing all units within that specific building, and not just the user's. If reworded, the series of things to happen is " Get all the units from building, now search each unit for a user where name is like 'blah' or search unit's parking spaces where parkingspace name is 'blah' ", does I make sense? This search is from the perspective of a building's manager. *but thank you, this is a cool feature, definitely added.*

Comment: Once you have narrowed down the collection to units to those that belong to the building, searching for the users or parking spaces is more straightforward.

Comment: That's correct, isn't doing $building->units()->whereHas('users',function($query) use($request){  name like etc.. }) doing just that?